# git clone/push gives error: Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive). assembla

Tags: git, assembla

I am trying to pull/push the code from a repo on assembla but I am facing this error all the times. 
[image]

I already uploaded the key to assembla account but still facing this issue.

Comment: `ssh -vvv git@whatever.is.your.provider.domain`.  But did you try your provider's support line?

Comment: @AlexanderPogrebnyak what is this command for?

Comment: To troubleshoot your 'ssh' connection issues

Comment: @AlexanderPogrebnyak this is what I got after running the command http://prntscr.com/d8z1mc

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I followed these instructions from assembla and was able to clone a repository from there:

[image: alt]

The only thing of note is, that I had to create the following entry in ~/.ssh/config:

`Host assembla
    Hostname git.assembla.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_assembla
    IdentitiesOnly yes`

followed by using the following clone command:

`git clone "assembla:username^reponame.git"`

From your [snapshot](http://prnt.sc/d8z1mc), it would appear that you are using Windows, therefore the location of the private key (id_rsa_assembla or whatever you are using) as well as the location of the ssh_config file will depend on how you installed git. See [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/194567/how-do-i-tell-git-for-windows-where-to-find-my-private-rsa-key) question.

Comment: thank you man, your answer and @Dan's answer [here](http://serverfault.com/questions/194567/how-do-i-tell-git-for-windows-where-to-find-my-private-rsa-key) solved my issue. Especially this step
"Note: Comments indicate that this doesn't work in all cases. You may need to copy the OpenSSH key to Program Files\Git\.ssh\id_rsa (or Program Files (x86)\Git\.ssh\id_rsa)."

Answer (score 3):

In case someone faced this problem in Windows -> Git Bash and the above didnt work, when copying from the website and pasting (CNTRL + Insert in Git Bash) directly from the web it inserts some special characters at the start of the string, leading to this error:

\302\226git@gitlab.com: Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).

Make sure you delete those special characters, or try manually typing the command.